# How to check the duplicates property in array of objects based on condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have array of object `arrayobj` in which have to check property value of

`code` and `type` based on condition return statement `no add` or `can add` in javascript

in arrobj `for type-local, if type local and code values not reappearing in other object`
return '**can add**' else return 'no add'

in arrobj `for type-FL or FL Travel, if different type and code values reappearing in other object`
return '**can add**'

in arrobj `for type-FL or FL Travel if type and code both reappearing in object` 
return '**no add**'

How to check above condition in javascript,

have tried code without checking property `type`, got stuck

```
function checkValues(arrob){
 const checkcode = arrob.map(elem => elem.code);
if (arrob.length !== new Set(checkcode).size) {
 return "no add";
} else {
 return "can add"
}
}
checkValues(arrobj1);
checkValues(arrobj2);
checkValues(arrobj3);

sample objects for scenario

var  arrobj1=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", code: "NIXZ", type: "Local"},
  {id:2, name: "abey", code: "ABCN", type: "FI"},
  {id:3, name: "jaz", code: "ABCN", type: "FI Travel"}
]
var  arrobj2=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", code: "NIXZ", type: "Local"},
  {id:4, name: "zain", code: "NIXZ", type: "FI"},
  {id:2, name: "abey", code: "ABCN", type: "FI"},
  {id:3, name: "jaz", code: "ABCNE", type: "FI Travel"}
]
var  arrobj3=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", code: "NIXZ", type: "Local"},
  {id:4, name: "sam", code: "ABCN", type: "FI"},
  {id:2, name: "abey", code: "ABCN", type: "FI"},
  {id:3, name: "jaz", code: "ABCNE", type: "FI Travel"}
]
```

Expected Result

```
//for arrobj1 [type-FL or FL Travel, different type and same code appears]
can add

//for arrobj2 [type local, same code appears] 
no add

//for arrobj3 [type-FL or FL Travel, same type and same code appears] 
no add
```

Answer (score -1):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const rawArray = [arrobj1 , arrobj2 , arrobj3]
const hasDups = (objArray) => {
    objArray.ForEach(el => {
        if (objArray.Includes(el.type))
            return true;
        return false;
    });    
}
const newArray = rawArray.map(el => !hasDups(el));
```

Comment: thanks but it fails, not matching the conditions