# check for duplicates in multiple fields in array of objects based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I have array of object in which return true or false based on duplicates

based on below conditions return true or false in javascript

if the `if type is local has duplicate code` value in object array return `true`

if the `if type is IN or IN travel has duplicate code` value in object array return `false`

if the `if same type IN and has same code` value in object array return `true`

if the `if same type IN Travel and has same code` value in object array return `true`

```
var  objarray1=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", code: "NIXZ", type: "Local"},
  {id:2, name: "abey", code: "ABCN", type: "IN"},
  {id:3, name: "jaz", code: "ABCN", type: "IN Travel"}
]

Expected Result 
// since type-IN or IN travel and code has duplicate
false
```

```
// this code not working for above conditions
function checkArrayObject(arrobj){
   
  const getLocal = arrobj.filter(e=>e.type=="local");
  const checklocalcode = arrobj.filter(e=>e.type=="local").map(i=>i.code);

  const getIN = arrobj.filter(e=>e.type=="IN");
  const checkINcode = arrobj.filter(e=>e.type=="IN").map(i=>i.code);
  var result = arrobj.forEach(e=>{
    if(getLocal.length === checklocalcode.length) {
      return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
    if(getIN.length === checkINcode.length){
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
     
   }
  })
}
```

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793186/how-to-check-the-duplicates-property-in-array-of-objects-based-on-condition-java

Comment: thanks for reply yes, but i thought its not clear thats y

Comment: You can update your original post with clear information. Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the duplicates property in array of objects based on condition javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793186/how-to-check-the-duplicates-property-in-array-of-objects-based-on-condition-java)

Comment: @Pellay thanks for reply, no it doesnt work, fails my conditions

Answer (score -1):

```
const filter = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
      if (i !== j && arr[i].code == arr[j].code)
        return false;

  return true;
};
```

Comment: Hey num num, You probably don't want to answer reposted questions. Post your answer on the OP's original question. You can find a link in the above comments or by viewing their profile.

Comment: @num num thanks for reply, but it does not work for conditions, can find the same  question of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793186/how-to-check-the-duplicates-property-in-array-of-objects-based-on-condition-java